# SwiftUI Sidebar with collapsing Button

Tags: macos, button, swiftui, sidebar

I try to add an "add" button to a sidebar within a `NavigationSplitView` of a `macos` apps same as found in the Xcode window.
Using this code within the sidebar-view does create the button at the top of the view but it is NOT going to hide when collapsing the sidebar.

```
.toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
            Button(action: addUser) {
                Label("Create New User",
                      systemImage: "person.crop.circle.badge.plus")
            }
            .help("New User")
        }
```

How to create a sidebar-view specific button at the bottom that sticks to the sidebar and is hidden when the sidebar is collapsing?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Is that really the toolbar? Can't you just use some `VStack`s and `HStack`s  to put a `Button` in that position?

Comment: @Sweeper, thanks for the answer guiding in the right direction. ScottM's proposal to use `.safeAreaInset` is what I was looking for though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SwiftUI for macOS, none of the `ToolbarItemPlacement` options available for positioning toolbar items corresponds to the bottom of the sidebar.

However, you can achieve something similar by placing controls within your view. While you could potentially place them in a ZStack or a VStack, an alternative (and some might say more idiomatic) approach is to use `.safeAreaInset`. For example:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                ForEach(1..<100, id: \.self) { i in
                    Text("Sidebar Item \(i)")
                }
            }
            .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
                HStack {
                    Button("Add", systemImage: "plus") { }
                    Spacer()
                }
                .controlSize(.small)
                .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                .padding(8)
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("Detail")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: An example of a sidebar with a bottom bar using .safeAreaInset]

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I was looking for. I never have heard/read about that `.saveAreaInset` before! Thanks a lot.